# iPhone Filling UITableView with JSON results (using search entered in UISearchBar)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, uitableview

Does anyone have a link to a tutorial for using a UISearchBar as the entry for a search, and a UITableView to display results returned in JSON?

Thank you!

Please no suggestions to RTFM - I can't find anything about using a UISearchBar for a remote search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the UISearchBarDelegate methods in your class. Then you can hit the web service in this delegate method

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
//Hit the webservice from here using searchBar.text

}
```

or if u need a dynamic search you can use the following method.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

}
```

After getting the data from the server update the datasource of your tableView and call the
(You can use SBJSON parser to parse your JSON response)

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```